# Disable GraphiQL playground on production in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, graphiql

I have added pom dependency in the spring boot application for graphiql playground with the "**graphiql-spring-boot-starter-5.0.2.jar**" dependency.

Now I would like to disable the playground for the production environment.

And have tried with spring boot applications as below, but none of these options working to disable the GraphiQL endpoint.

1. graphiql.enabled= false
2. dgs.graphql.graphiql.enabled=false

Could you please suggest how we could disable GraphiQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add the below configuration in your production profile inside application.yml or application.properties to disable the playground in the production.

I have tested it with **com.graphql-java:playground-spring-boot-started:11.0.0**

In application.yml

```yaml
graphql:
 playground:
  enabled: false
```

In application.properties

`graphql.playground.enabled = false`